# Retrieving data from localStorage and showing it in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data from localStorage and showcase all entries on the table but I can't access the key.

The last `console.log` shows specific entry. `myFunction()` `console.log` shows all entries but when I am trying to `return` all entries, I get `Cannot read property 'KlientoNr'` error. In the second `<td>` I am trying to access entries directly but I get `undifiend`. How to properly show all entries to a table?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  const clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  const odontologas = clients.Odontologas;

  const myFunction = () => {
    const arrayLength = odontologas.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      console.log(odontologas[i].KlientoNr);
    }
    return odontologas[i].KlientoNr;
  };

  $.each(odontologas, function() {
    $("#odontologas").append(`<tr>
      <td>${myFunction()}</td>
      <td>${odontologas.EilėsNr}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
          Aptarnautas
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>`);
  });
  console.log(odontologas[7].KlientoNr);
});
```

Comment: You are using the variable `i` outside of the for loop in `return odontologas[i].KlientoNr;` Just return `odontologas;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `${odontologas.EilėsNr}` is `odontologas` is the whole array and has no property `EilėsNr`

Use the arguments passed to the each callback to access specific object instance

```
 $.each(odontologas, function(i, item) {
    $("#odontologas").append(`<tr>
      ...
      <td>${item.EilėsNr}</td>
      // OR
      <td>${odontologas[i].EilėsNr}</td>
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code. For example, the myFunction, it runs a for loop from i=0 till length of the array. If array has say 8 elements. Then when i becomes 8 then only the loop will break. And after the for loop you've returning  odontologas[i].KlientoNr; But i is 8 and there is no item on this index. So it is returning undefined.

Second issue is, in the html part you wrote odontologas.EilėsNr. odontologas is an array. There is no index here. So this will also return undefined.